# Git - return code 22

Tags: git

Olá,

Sou novo no `Git` e estou tentando fazer a manutenção de um site simples com ele, que até então eu fazia por `FTP`.

Então. Criei uma pasta nova para testes no servidor (utilizo hospedagem da `GoDaddy`). Dentro da pasta, iniciei um novo repositório. Clonei o repositório para minha máquina. Adicionei um arquivo, e fiz um `commit`, apenas para testes. Agora é que vem: quando utilizo o comando `Push`, ele retorna:

> error: Cannot access URL http://nvinhadeluz.com/pastateste/.git/,
>   return code 22 fatal: git-http-push failed error: failed to push some
>   refs to  'http://nvinhadeluz.com/pastateste/.git/'

Grato desde já por qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Já fez [isso](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Configurando-o-Servidor)?

Comment: Não. Simplesmente tentei ir direto para a parte prática. Grato pelo link. Darei retorno assim que possível.

Comment: Documentação perfeita. Tudo funciona como esperado. Grato!